# Check-in code into TFS Server by using TFS API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm writing c# code to check-in code to TFS server:

```
Workspace WS = VersionControl.GetWorkspace(TeamProject);
WS.Map(TFSMapServerPath,LocalWorkingPath);

int NumberOfChange = WS.PendAdd(string.Format(@"{0}\Main\DotNet\",LocalWorkingPath),true);

PendingChange[] pendingChanges = WS.GetPendingChanges();        
WS.CheckIn(pendingChanges,"Auto Check-in");
```

But i got the error is

> "No files checked in", all files/folders under LocalWorkingPath are "Pending Change".

Are the above codes correct?

Comment: get latest and check if you see your code there, sometimes the code checked in but the TFS write that it not.

Comment: I used my account to check TFS Server, files/ folder are there but the status is "pending changes" and i need to manually check-in by right click on that and click on check-in.

Comment: If Team project already there, files or folders checked-in sucessfully otherwise it is "pending Change". Do we have any ways to check-in automatically in case of Team Project doesn't exist in TFS Server?

Comment: VersionControl.GetWorkspace takes in the local workspace path and not team project. And yes the project has to exist for you checkin anything against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the command WS.GetPendingChanges() to WS.GetPendingChanges(tfsServerFolderPath,RecursionType.Full) and it is working at my side.

Here is detail:

```
        //Get the current workspace
        WS = versionControl.GetWorkspace(workspaceName, versionControl.AuthorizedUser);     

        //Mapping TFS Server and code generated
        WS.Map(tfsServerFolderPath,localWorkingPath);

        //Add all files just created to pending change
        int NumberOfChange = WS.PendAdd(localWorkingPath,true);
        //Get the list of pending changes
        PendingChange[] pendings = WS.GetPendingChanges(tfsServerFolderPath,RecursionType.Full);

        //Auto check in code to Server
        WS.CheckIn(pendings,"CodeSmith Generator - Auto check-in code.");
```

Comment: What reference do you use in order to make this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This approach doesn't work for folders and when I tried to check-in only folders without files inside, I get an exception: "No files checked in.".