# Issue with API Deleting for Team Foundation Server TFS

Tags: api, tfs

Hello can anyone tell me how to delete files using the API for TFS?  Below is what I have but I can not get it to work any help would really be appreciated.

```
string[] InLocalDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(LogicAppConfig.Query(AppConfigLogic.TypeOfConfig.Path), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// Source Control
List<string> InSourceControl = new List<string>();
ItemSet SetOfItem = _ServerVersionControl.GetItems(_ServerPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full);
foreach (Item GotItem in SetOfItem.Items)
{
    ItemType TypeOfItem = GotItem.ItemType;
    if (TypeOfItem == ItemType.File)
    {
        string LocalPath = _WorkspaceLocal.GetLocalItemForServerItem(GotItem.ServerItem);
        InSourceControl.Add(LocalPath);
    }
}

List<int> ToDeleteById = new List<int>();
foreach (string SourceFile in InSourceControl)
{
    if (!IsIgnored(SourceFile) && !InLocalDirectory.Contains(SourceFile))
    {
        // Delete Source Control File
        Item DeleteItem = _ServerVersionControl.GetItem(SourceFile);
        ToDeleteById.Add(DeleteItem.ItemId);
        // Update Local XML Directory
        DataXml.Delete(SourceFile);
    }
}

WorkItemStore wis = _CollectionTeamProject.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
wis.DestroyWorkItems(ToDeleteById);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant error messages within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

namespace ConsoleAppX
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
            creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://tfsuri"), creds);
            TfvcHttpClient tfvcClient = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
            TfvcItem ti = tfvcClient.GetItemAsync("ProjectName", "$/FilePath","FileName").Result;
            TfvcChange tchange = new TfvcChange(ti,VersionControlChangeType.Delete);          
            List<TfvcChange> change = new List<TfvcChange> { tchange };
            TfvcChangeset tchangeset = new TfvcChangeset();
            tchangeset.Changes = change;
            tfvcClient.CreateChangesetAsync(tchangeset);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved it I just deleted my entire project out of TFS using this... opps... backup running now...

Comment: Look like it is an API issue from version 6 to 7 where 7 is not backward compatible with deleting.  I also ran into this with workspace deleting via API as well.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a file, you need to use the [VersionControlServer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) to get an existing Workspace or create a new workspace. The workspace has a PendDelete method to create pending changes in the workspace. Then use the Workspace.Checkin method to commit them to source control:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried the penddelete before I tried the last way of doing it.  But even when I manually go and delete a file and it hits the _WorkspaceLocal.PendDelete(SourceFile); line and is inserted for deletion it does not pick up on the line if (changes.Count() > 0) and then never check in.

```
string[] InLocalDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(LogicAppConfig.Query(AppConfigLogic.TypeOfConfig.Path), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            // Source Control
            List<string> InSourceControl = new List<string>();
            ItemSet SetOfItem = _ServerVersionControl.GetItems(_ServerPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full);
            foreach (Item GotItem in SetOfItem.Items)
            {
                ItemType TypeOfItem = GotItem.ItemType;
                if (TypeOfItem == ItemType.File)
                {
                    string LocalPath = _WorkspaceLocal.GetLocalItemForServerItem(GotItem.ServerItem);
                    InSourceControl.Add(LocalPath);
                }
            }

            List<int> ToDeleteById = new List<int>();
            foreach (string SourceFile in InSourceControl)
            {
                if (!IsIgnored(SourceFile) && !InLocalDirectory.Contains(SourceFile))
                {
                    // Delete Source Control File
                    Item DeleteItem = _ServerVersionControl.GetItem(SourceFile);
                    ToDeleteById.Add(DeleteItem.ItemId);
                    // Update Local XML Directory
                    DataXml.Delete(SourceFile);
                    // Set for Deletion
                    _WorkspaceLocal.PendDelete(SourceFile);
                }
            }

            string ConflictMessage = "";
            Conflict[] conflicts = _WorkspaceLocal.QueryConflicts(new string[] { _LocalPath }, true);
            foreach (Conflict conflict in conflicts)
            {
                if (conflict != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (conflict.CanMergeContent)
                        {
                            conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptMerge;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptYoursRenameTheirs;
                        }
                        ConflictMessage += @"\n\r\n\r" + conflict.GetFullMessage();
                        _WorkspaceLocal.ResolveConflict(conflict);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogicAppConfig.Insert(AppConfigLogic.TypeOfConfig.Message, "Error Detected Previously:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.Source + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n\r\n" + LogicAppConfig.Query(AppConfigLogic.TypeOfConfig.Path));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConflictMessage))
            {
                LogicAppConfig.Insert(AppConfigLogic.TypeOfConfig.Message, ConflictMessage);
            }

            PendingChange[] changes = _WorkspaceLocal.GetPendingChanges();

            if (changes.Count() > 0)
            {
                int ChangeSetId = _WorkspaceLocal.CheckIn(changes, _WorkspaceName + " Deleted by Member Collaboration Utility");
            }
```

Comment: Try to change `_WorkspaceLocal.GetPendingChanges()` to `_WorkspaceLocal.GetPendingChanges(tfsServerFolderPath,RecursionType.Full)` to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: No that did not work either I'm not sure what is going on with this API...

Comment: Check the answer in the following case to see whether it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487590/check-in-code-into-tfs-server-by-using-tfs-api

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing still I don't get anything. The only difference is I use pending delete and not pending add.